# Incorrect result when integrating

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

*Mathematica* 10.4.1.0 produces

```
Integrate[
  Log[1 + 2 a*Cos[2 x] + a^2]*Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, Pi/2}, 
  Assumptions -> a > 1
]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[1/4 Pi (-1 + 2 Log[a]), a < 3]
> ```

whereas the correct result is $$ \frac\pi 4\left(\ln a^2 -\frac 1 a\right) $$ according to [Gradshtein & Ryzhik, formula 4.397.14](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=aBgFYxKHUjsC&pg=PA590).

How to correct this defect?

Comment: The conditional expression generic formula seems not to match a particular case, `Integrate[Log[1 + 2 2*Cos[2 x] + 2^2]*Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, Pi/2}]` (which matches GR).

Comment: `NIntegrate[]` works fine here if it's of any help. `l = Transpose[{Range[1, 3, 0.1], Table[
     NIntegrate[
      Log[1 + 2 a*Cos[2 x] + a^2]*Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, Pi/2}], {a, 1, 3, 
      0.1}]}];`
`ListPlot[l]`

Answer (score 7):

Using the conditions in the book

```
ClearAll[a, x];
expr = Log[1 + 2 a*Cos[2 x] + a^2]*Sin[x]^2;
r = Integrate[expr, {x, 0, Pi/2}, Assumptions -> a^2 > 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Book result

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You used $a>1$ but the book says to use $a^2>1$. These are not the same.

---

Update:  I asked about this on another forum. Experts opinions says that result should be valid for $|a|>1$ and not just $a^2>1$.  [reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math.symbolic/HnKRQa7xMC8).  So the result given should also apply for $a>1$.

Comment: @ Naser: Thank you. How about the case $a>1$ which implies $a^2>1$?

Comment: @user64494 $a>1$ implies $a^2>1$, but $a^2>1$ does not imply $a>1$ and the result in the book is valid for $a^2>1$ which agrees with what M gives. Now for $a>1$ the result is what you show in your question. Which I assume is correct.

Comment: This gives the conditional expression that `a< -1`, even though it is valid for `a>1` too.

Comment: @Feyre You might be right. I updated the answer with link.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I am using 10.4.1, 64 bit, on windows 7 64 bits. Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1Es9c.png)  if you are not on windows, then this means there is platform difference !

Comment: Yep, I'm on "10.4.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)". , BUT....It seems something was cached.  Here's a shot from a fresh kernel: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SGpQx.png

Comment: @Naser : You wrote "I asked about this on another forum. Experts opinions says that result should be valid for $|a|>1 $ and not just $a^2>1$.So the result given should also apply for $a>1$". Could you kindly elabotate this in detail? I see Mma produces the conditional expression for $a < -1$ only. Therefore, this output does not answer the question.

Comment: @user64494 But I gave the link there to the discussion so any one can read it. It is google group link. It seems based on what was said, that the book and M are in error and the result should be valid for |a|>1 and not a^2>1.  Please read the replies in the link I give. In Particular, the reply by Martin there.

Comment: `ShowSteps = False` -- is that something left over from Rubi?

Comment: @ Nasser: First, I am very sorry for the  bad spelling of your name. Second,   in the rich-in-content thread Martin wrote "Note that your Mathematica result (unnecessarily) limits itself to $a <-1$. It is invalid for $|a| < 1$ though ". No more and no less.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, I was trying Rubi on the integral before and had that line there. Will remove it now. Thanks.